# numpy array print index of certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given a numpy array

```
A = np.array([[[29, 64, 83],
               [17, 92, 38],
               [67, 34, 20]],
              [[73, 28, 45],
               [19, 84, 61],
               [22, 63, 49]],
              [[48, 30, 13],
               [11, 52, 86],
               [62, 25, 12]]])
```

I want the index of a certain value, say 63

There is no possibility that the value will be duplicated or missing

I did

```
idx = np.where(A == 63)

print(idx)
```

I got

```
(array([1], dtype=int32), array([2], dtype=int32), array([1], dtype=int32))
```

What I want is

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

as a list or other iterable without all that `array, dtype=int32` etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

What about this approach using [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
   idx = [x[0] for x in np.where(A==63)]
```

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks. I will have to study it to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Check out list comprehension if yo want to know how it works.

Comment: What I don't understand is what the  0 in x[0] is doing

Comment: It's pulling of the value from the array[...]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a numpy array back, just use the [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function:

```
In [30]: np.concatenate(idx)
Out[30]: array([1, 2, 1])
```

If you really have your heart set on a Python list, then just:

```
In [31]: np.concatenate(idx).tolist()
Out[31]: [1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays support returning elements where a condition is true. You can use `np.where(..)` or use:

```
>>> A==63
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

You can then flatten that index array to only the True values using an array's `.nonzero()` method:

```
>>> (A==63).nonzero()
(array([1]), array([2]), array([1]))
```

Note that is a Python tuple of numpy arrays with the first being the X index, the second being the Y and then Z in `A[X,Y,Z]` form.

For one element only, you could then flatten that using `.r_`:

```
>>> np.r_[(A==63).nonzero()]
array([1, 2, 1])
```

And you can produce a Python list if you wish:

```
>>> np.r_[(A==63).nonzero()].tolist()
[1, 2, 1]
```

A more interesting use case is when you have more than one index in the matrix that is True. Consider all values >63:

```
>>> A>63
array([[[False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[ True, False, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

You can also use .nonzero() method or the nonzero function:

```
>>> np.nonzero(A>63)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1]), array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]))
     ^^^ X's                      ^^^ Y's                              ^^^ Z's
```

Notice now that this is a tuple of 3 arrays (in this case) of all X's, all Y's, all Z's in that order.

You can use `np.transpose` to produce an array of those element indexes of the form `[[X, Y, Z],...]` like so:

```
>>> np.transpose((A>63).nonzero())
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2]])
```

Or (suitable for printing for human eyes for example) you can use `zip`:

```
>>> zip(*(A>63).nonzero())
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2)]
```

Or, to print:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([str(e) for e in zip(*(A>63).nonzero())])
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
```

Which, of course, would work for a single element just as well:

```
>>> zip(*(A==63).nonzero())[0]
(1, 2, 1)
```

Or numpy way:

```
>>> np.transpose((A==63).nonzero())[0]
array([1, 2, 1])
```

All the methods here works with `np.where(A==63)` in place of `(A==63).nonzero()` as an example.